# How can I show a image in a dialogue with jQuery mobile?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, jquery-mobile

I've tried using several plugins : code.photoswipe-3.0.4 ,NETEYE-touch-gallery-1.0.0, both of which have either incomplete instructions on how to use, or just plain don't work.

Is it because of the jquery/jquery mobile versions I am using ? its 1.6.4/1.0.1

Followed the instructions to the point and when I click the links, i get a new page with "undefined" on it. Have not been able to fix the problem. Any help would be much appreciated.

When i used photoswipe this is what i did

I put this on the header as stated on the photoswipe website:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var myPhotoSwipe = $("#Gallery a").photoSwipe({ enableMouseWheel: false , enableKeyboard: false });

});
```

and this in the gallery div (which has data-role="controlgroup"):

```
<ul id="Gallery">
<li>
<a href="../images/course_img/1_full.jpg"> <!--adding the rel=external simply opens the image in a new website page.>
<img src="../images/course_img/1_thumb.png"</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

all i got was either undefined error, or broken links or the image shown in a separate webpage.

Now i dumped the whole extra script approach and went with something more stupid and simple. To my surprise, this won't work either !

```
      <a href="../images/course_img/1_full.jpg" data-rel="dialog">
        <img src="../images/course_img/1_thumb.png"/>
      </a>
```

Can you please help me out with a pointer or 2 ? Much appreciated !
I'm working with dreamweaver cs6 and chrome latest on x64 system. I ran the link checker on the page several times and the links are all fine, unless I'm missing something !

In the javascript console, this is what I get when I press the link above:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///E:/GoogleCloud/Google%20Drive/git/TestApp/images/course_img/1_full.jpg. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Answer (score 0):

after some digging it looks like for some stupid reason you cannot use jpegs in dw. they display as broken links or file missing.
ex:

if you do

```
<a href="blabla.jpeg">
  <img src="blublu.png"/>
</a>
```

the link will not display properly. Both images have to have the same format. Stupid, but true. another thing i found out is that after implementing the code on photoswipe website
i still get a

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```